# Taking intersections of convex hulls in boost::geometry

Tags: c++, boost, convex-hull, set-intersection, boost-geometry

After several attempts using floating point numbers that resulted in wild exceptions because of rounding issues, I thought using integer arithmetic as a workaround did the trick.  However, now I run into the exact same issue.

I'm trying to compute the intersection of the convex hulls of various point sets:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/multi/geometries/multi_point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<int> Point;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::multi_point<Point> MultiPoint;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::ring<Point> Polygon;

    MultiPoint mp0, mp1;
    boost::geometry::read_wkt("MULTIPOINT((54 74),(54 75),(54 75),(62 75),(86 75),(94 75),(118 75),(124 75),(13 50),(13 51),(147 130),(281 51),(281 50))", mp0);
    boost::geometry::read_wkt("MULTIPOINT((52 74),(54 75),(135 90),(175 74),(54 74),(52 74))", mp1);

    Polygon hull0, hull1;
    boost::geometry::convex_hull(mp0, hull0);
    boost::geometry::convex_hull(mp1, hull1);

    std::vector<Polygon> results;
    boost::geometry::intersection(hull0, hull1, results);

    assert(results.size() == 1);

    // This results in the exception.
    assert(!boost::geometry::detail::overlay::has_self_intersections(results[0]));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This fails with `boost::geometry::overlay_invalid_input_exception`.

The convex hulls `hull0` and `hull1` look like this:

[image: hull0 and hull1]

Is there something I am doing wrong?  I'd really like to not have to implement computing the convex hull and intersections myself, which seems like a lot of unnecessary error prone work.

Comment: `has_self_intersections` can only return `false` or throw the exception. It was likely not intended for general use, since it's hidden in the `detail` namespace.

Comment: @Cubbi, yes, and it's used by many functions to check the consistency of the underlying data.  Therefore if it fails, things will go wrong the next time one uses ```results[0]```.

Answer (score 1):

The use-case looks ok.

We have some numerical robustness upgrades but they're not released yet (Boost 1.55). If you'd like to test them or ask some more detailed questions I suggest to contact us on the Boost.Geometry mailing list: http://lists.boost.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/geometry.

Comment: I filed this bug report: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9934  The bug can be reproduced with the current git repository which I suppose contains the robustness upgrades?

Comment: No, they're in the branch rescale_to_integer. Keep in mind that it's work in progress. For future readers: this branch may no longer exist and the updates might be merged with develop and/or master.

Comment: Thanks, I now resolved it for now by resorting to converting everything to a boost::polygon polygon, intersecting there, and then converting it back to boost::geometry.  I need the code in a production environment and therefore cannot really use a work in progress code base.